# Error con php-curl en Servidor ubuntu

Tags: php, firebase, curl

Tengo un error al utilizar php - curl.

Este fichero de PHP me sirve para enviar notificaciones de mi servidor a firebase.

Lo he probado en un servidor local con windows y ese mismo fichero funciona perfectamente, pero cuando lo pruebo en mi servidor linux no funciona. En ese caso, al momento de colocar la url en en navegador este no me carga me queda en blanco y no me ejecuta nada.

```
    <?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', '');

$registrationIds = [""];


// prep the bundle
$msg = [
    'title' => 'titulo',
    'body' => 'Prueba '
];

$fields = [
    'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
    'notification' => $msg
];

$headers = [
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
];
$fields = json_encode( $fields );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );

echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: Buenas, por favor, revisa [ask] y [mcve] para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: ¿Qué te dice el log de apache?

Comment: **error.log.42.gz  ocsmanager-access.log.35.gz  ocsmanager-error.log.28.gz   ssl_access.log.18.gz**  esto es lo que me dice y eln la url de el navegador cuando recargo el json me sale en blanco

Comment: esos son los archivos de log casi seguro, revisalos. Tienes instalado cURL en tu servidor?

Comment: si esta instalado  curl pero nada sigue sin funcionar